# Highcharts labels formatter 'this.value' returns wrong time in milliseconds

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have following chart options:

```
{
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
      formatter: function () {
        //this = {xAxis: a.Axis, chart: a.Chart, dateTimeLabelFormat:"%e. %b", isFirst:true, isLast:false, value:1468195200000}
        var wrongTime = this.value; //1468195200000
      }
    }
  },
  series: {
    data: [
      [1473033600005, 10]
    ]
  }
}
```

When I trying to get 'x' value of point inside labels formatter function, **

> 'this.value' returns it without milliseconds

so I can't properly format label. When I hover this point on the chart, in tooltip displayed correct dateString with milliseconds.

I think that problem maybe in `'dateTimeLabelFormat'` property of 'this', but have no ideas how to fix it.

Comment: In axis.labels formatter you do not get value of the point, but value of the tick. If the tick is positioned in exactly the same place as the point (x coordinates) then the values will be the same. See example http://jsfiddle.net/xfpbo440/

Comment: @morganfree Thank you for your answer! Now I understood my mistake.